# Extend prepare() to Database class

Tags: php, oop

I'm using:

```
> $db = new Database(); // my own Database class

> $result = $db -> query(sql);

> $row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

... and it does so fine and without any issues. But often times the sql is changed a bit based on user input (or can be altered by user input), which I've learned is extremely susceptible to sql injection. Yikes.

So I've been reading up on prepared statements, and I'm ready to switch to something more like this:

```
> $db = new Database();

> $stmt = $db -> prepare(sql);

> if ($stmt->execute(array($_GET['name'])) {

> > while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

> > > print_r($row);
          
> > }

> }
```

... which I've grabbed from [example #3](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). I've altered my code to fit what I want but I'm getting `Call to undefined method Database::prepare()`, which I realize means I don't have the prepare() method available in the class. How can I extend this functionality? And if you don't mind, a little explanation might be helpful. :)

**Edit:** Here are the contents of my current Database class.

```
class Database {

private $link;
private $host = "#####";
private $username = "#####";
private $password = "####";
private $db = "####";

public function __construct(){
    $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db)
        OR die("There was a problem connecting to the database.");
    return true;
}

public function query($query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query);
    if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    return $result;
}

public function __destruct() {
    mysqli_close($this->link)
        OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");
}

}
```

Comment: @Nouphal.M edited to include my Database class.

Comment: Why do you **think** that you need a "database class"?

Comment: @teresko I guess I don't need it for what I'm doing. I just built a separate function that returns the link connection and it's working fine with the prepare and execute methods.

Answer (score 0):

Return the mysqli link from your construct or you could write a get method for returning the link.

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db)
        OR die("There was a problem connecting to the database.");
    return $this->link;
}
```

And try this:

```
 $db = new Database();
 $name = $_GET['name']; // try validating the user input here
 if( $stmt = $db->prepare($sql) ){
       $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);
       $stmt->execute();
       while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
           print_r($row);
       }
 }
```

Comment: I tried making this change, and still getting the error.

Comment: This kills encapsulation and removes the necessity of a Database class.

Answer (score 0):

Make `Database` extend `mysqli`

```
class Database extends mysqli
{

    private $link;
    private $host = "#####";
    private $username = "#####";
    private $password = "####";
    private $db = "####";

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->db)
        OR die("There was a problem connecting to the database.");
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        mysqli_close($this->link)
        OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");
    }

}
```

Then you can call $db as if it's a `mysqli` object

```
$db = new Database();
$db->query($sql);
```

BUT you should just use the `mysqli` object directly if you're not really adding any functionality to the class...

Comment: He is adding mysql error management (`OR die...`) in each method and I hope its done to reduce code duplication. It's a good decision, but I would throw exceptions instead of the `OR die` statements.

Comment: @Tomás in which case he should be using the much more updated `PDO` class, which actually throws exceptions, includes all the functionality of `mysqli`, and is slightly more advanced in features.